# How do I remove operation element from soap envelope body in WCF?

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service setup mostly to a customer's spec, yet there is one extra element required of an envelope body that I'm trying to exclude based on the customer's sample request.

These are my service and operation contracts:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.somenamespace.com")]
public interface IProcessPayment
{
    [OperationContract]
    ResponseSubmitPayment execute(RequestSubmitPayment RequestSubmitPayment);
}
```

This is what they are sending to test my service with:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pay="http://www.somenamespace.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <pay:RequestSubmitPayment>
       <!-- irrelevant stuff -->
    </pay:RequestSubmitPayment>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this is what my service expects (based on SOAPUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pay="http://www.somenamespace.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pay:execute> <!-- I want to remove this! -->
         <pay:RequestSubmitPayment>
            <!-- irrelevant stuff -->
         </pay:RequestSubmitPayment>
      </pay:execute> <!-- I want to remove this! -->
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I configure my WCF service to not require or exclude that  element?  The client has told me they have many other customers with it successfully tested and implemented.  SOAP 1.1 is my understanding of what they're sending.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure doable in operationcontract. try using a message contract, and if also does not work then use an xmlserializer contract with method flag ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare

Comment: Looks interesting!  I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @YaronNaveh Please post your response (in particular the MessageContract) as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is doable in operationcontract. Try using a message contract, it will give you the flexibility you need. If that fails use an xmlserializer contract with method flag ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare.

Comment: To clarify - MessageContract allowed me to do what I needed.

Comment: @Zach I got the same problem, Could you tell me how did you use MessageContract?

Comment: @KevinBui Oh boy this was a while ago but I believe my final solution ended up being a bit different.  I think I took the wsdl they had and generated the service based on that.  It was much nicer/cleaner.