# How do I remove operation element from soap body in WCF?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have wcf services using .net framework 4.0, all setting is default of visual studio WCF project

```
namespace ApiFrame{
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://abc.com.vn/")]public interface IApiframe
{

    [OperationContract(Name = "process", Action="")]
    string testprocess(string request);
```

this is what my service result (based on SOAPUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://abc.com.vn/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <api:testprocess><!-- I want to remove this! -->
         <!--Optional:-->
         <api:request></api:request>
      </api:testprocess><!-- I want to remove this! -->
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to remove `<api:process>` xml tag.

Comment: You cannot, it's part of your contract. You named "testprocess" operation as "process", that is exactly what is in your xml.

Comment: I read a topic about my problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573134/how-do-i-remove-operation-element-from-soap-envelope-body-in-wcf
But i can not do this

Comment: To change the request/response schema or generated xml you can use serviceContract/operationContrat attributes, that you already using, using messageContract (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute.aspx) or even writting a custom serializer/deserializer. As you said you cannot do it, there's no other way (that I know) that you can reach you goal.
Anyway, think about if you would have some operations in your service, if you omit the tag with the operation name, how can your service decide on which operation you want to execute?